# Liouville property in Z^d

Tags: pr.probability

It is well known that $\mathbb{Z}^d$ has Liouville property, i. e. every bounded harmonic function on this graph is constant.

(harmonic means that the value of $f$ in a point $x$ is equal to the average of $f$ over neighbours of $x$ in the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$).

What are the nicest/shortest/most ingenious proofs of this fact that you know?

Comment: This is almost a contest problem. Actually it has appeared in contests :) I think artofproblemsolving would be a better forum for your question.

Comment: I disagree - although there are completely elementary and short proofs of this fact, there are also more sophisticated ones that illustrate important mathematical techniques or results (e. g. Krein-Milman theorem, Markov chains).

Comment: There are at least 5 proofs in the link. The only additional thing requested in your question is which one is one's favorite proof. You haven't really explained how that is of any use to you or anyone else. http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=5327&hilit=very+hard

Comment: So, if you know several (elementary) proofs, what do you ask?! And what's your motivation to ask? (This could be curiosity, of course.)

Comment: I'm asking out of curiosity, what's so strange about that?

Comment: I wonder wether there is an elementary proof for functions bounded from belov (a priori not from above).

Comment: @Fedor: Yes. Choose $f\ge0$ with $f(0)=1$ to maximize the sum of squares of $f(x)$ over $\Vert x\Vert\le1$ (we have compactness). Using the fact that the triangle inequality for a sum of vectors is an equality iff all the vectors are proportional, you can deduce that $f(x+e_i)=K_if(x)$ for constants $K_i$. Then, $f(x)=K_1^{x_1}\cdots K_d^{x_d}$. This only satisfies the harmonic condition if $K_i=1$, so $f\equiv1$, and the variance of the values of $f(x)$ over $\Vert x\le1$ is 0. As $f$ was chosen to maximize the variance, the values of any harmonic $f\ge0$ has 0 variance. So it is constant.

Comment: @Fedor: To see that the set of harmonic $f\ge0$ with $f(0)=1$ is compact, note that $f(x)\le2df(y)$ for neighboring points $x,y$. So the set of such $f$ is locally bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Yuval Peres gave a fairly short proof of this result in his lectures at the 2009 Cornell Probability Summer School (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~durrett/CPSS2009/peres6.pdf).

If one wants to use more machinery from probability theory, the Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law implies that the tail $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{T}$ associated with the SRW on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ is trivial.  But the tail $\sigma$-field is a superset of the 'invariant' sigma field $\mathcal{I} := \{F\in\mathcal{F}:F\circ \theta_n = F \text{ for all }n\}$, and the invariant sigma field being $\mathbb{P}^x$-trivial for all $x$ is equivalent to the graph having the Liouville property.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that last statement about the Liouville property being equivalent to $P^x$-triviality for all $x$?